# How to handle deleted entity using ApplyAbpConceptsForDeletedEntity (concurrency)

Tags: entity-framework

Hi there does anyone know how to handle delete concurrecy if an entity gets deleted having two tabs opened with the same entites and deleting the entity in the first tab and trying to make changes to the entity in the second tab and saving that?

Example of concurrency RowVersion working if two users edit the same entity:

```
        protected override void ApplyAbpConceptsForModifiedEntity(EntityEntry entry, long? userId, EntityChangeReport changeReport)
    {
        //Get the entity being tracked.
        var entity = entry.Entity;

        if (entity.GetType().GetProperty("RowVersion") != null)
        {
            entry.OriginalValues["RowVersion"] = entry.CurrentValues["RowVersion"];
        }
        base.ApplyAbpConceptsForModifiedEntity(entry, userId, changeReport);
    }
```

Example of delete entity not sure how to get this working if two users make different changes e.g. edit and delete at the same time:

```
        protected override void ApplyAbpConceptsForDeletedEntity(EntityEntry entry, long? userId, EntityChangeReport changeReport)
    {
        base.ApplyAbpConceptsForDeletedEntity(entry, userId, changeReport);
    }
```

Comment: The update will simply fail with a DbUpdateException.

Comment: This exception only fires when trying to edit to entites. But when I try to use it with deleting it doesnt throw an exception.

Comment: Well, with this amount of information it's impossible to tell what's going on. Try to post a [mcve] .

Comment: @GertArnold I have added code examples.